# applicationDidBecomeActive: Am I causing a memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Using ARC, I'm calling the following function in an iOS app every time the app gets opened in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` function.

My concern is that it could create a memory leak because it's creating new instances of `UIViewControllers` every time the app gets opened from the background.

```
- (void)showMainWindow{
  NSLog(@"@Info @AppDelegate: Showing Main Window");
  self.leftMenuViewController = nil;
  self.rightMenuViewController = nil;
  MenuViewController *tempLeft = [[MenuViewController alloc]initWithSide:@"left"];
  MenuViewController *tempRight = [[MenuViewController alloc]initWithSide:@"right"];
  self.leftMenuViewController = tempLeft;
  self.rightMenuViewController = tempRight;
  self.viewDeckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.webViewController
                                                                                leftViewController:self.leftMenuViewController
                                                                               rightViewController:self.rightMenuViewController];

  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewDeckController;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateNavigationBar" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, though it might depend on if the view deck controller retains the web view controller. simple way to check though: run in instruments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code doesn't appear to leak. To be sure, however, you should use the `leaks` instrument to periodically check your code.

To do such,

1. Select Product -> Profile (or, ⌘ I)
2. Choose `Leaks`
3. Select Profile
4. Exercise your app (i.e. go through all the options, background it, etc)

For more information on using the leaks tool, you can checkout Ray Wenderlich's [Instruments Tutorial for iOS: How to Debug Memory Leaks](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/).

**Additional Notes:**

1) Unless you have a really good reason to, you shouldn't be setting `self.window.rootViewController` every time that the app returns to the foreground. Instead of calling `showMainWindow` from within `applicationDidBecomeActive`, you should probably move this code within `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, which is the more common place to do  initial app setup.

Further, if you need a controller to know when the app has entered the foreground (I imagine that this is the reason you're actually doing this), you should have it register to receive notification of `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. I.e.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(YOUR_SELECTOR)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                           object:nil];

    // ... whatever else you do here...
}

// Also make sure to unregister too
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

2) To make this code a bit more cleaner and easier to read, I would rewrite it like this:

```
- (void)showMainWindow 
{

    NSLog(@"@Info @AppDelegate: Showing Main Window");

    self.leftMenuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc]initWithSide:@"left"];;
    self.rightMenuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc]initWithSide:@"right"];;

    self.viewDeckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.webViewController
                                                                                leftViewController:self.leftMenuViewController
                                                                           rightViewController:self.rightMenuViewController];

  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewDeckController;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateNavigationBar" object:nil];
}
```

In such, you don't have to explicitly set `self.leftMenuViewController` and `self.rightMenuViewController` to `nil` or create the `temp` objects.